# Using split() with awk

Tags: awk, split

I am trying to use split() with awk. I am splitting the contents of $7 with split() into an array, but not sure how to print the contents starting from reverse order. The field $7 is of variable length, but the text I require is the 4, 5, 6 from he end of the array.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "=" } ; { print $4,"\n", $5"="$6, split($7,a," "); print a[-3] ,"\n\n\n" }' test.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be what you want:

```
n=split($7,a," "); print a[n-3], a[n-4], a[n-5]
```

If not then edit your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates your problem.

See the [GNU Awk Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-split_0028_0029-function-1) for more insight.

Comment: this worked thanks.